# a4j:commandbutton within f:ajax nested does not execute oncomplete

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

As you can see below, I have a f:ajax nested in a a4j:commandLink, something similar to what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965897/field-id-conflict-inside-a-jsf-form-with-datagrid?rq=1) in order to solve a saving-on-db issue.

Now, when I click the commandLink, oncomplete is never call. That means, the modal does not close and the cursor keeps on "waiting" mode. If I remove the f:ajax, oncomplete is called but the saving-on-database comes back.

I have already tried several things but no one actually worked. Does anyway what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance

```
<a4j:commandLink value="#{msg.label_accept}"
        onclick="this.disabled=true; document.body.style.cursor='wait';"
        action="#{backingBeanRef['select']}"
        oncomplete="this.disabled=false; document.body.style.cursor='auto';closeModal('modalDocumentationCenter');"
        styleClass="btn btn-default btn-einvoice"
        render="@this">
        <f:ajax execute="inputTitle inputDescription"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a4j:commandLink` has ajax already. So use `execute` from `a4j:commandLink` directly. Don't use another ajax tag. You can't (or, for sure, you shouldn't) use both.

Or I you really want to use `f:ajax`, then use `h:commandLink` instead of `a4j:commandLink`.

PS. You can try to use `a4j:ajax`, but I'm pretty sure the result will be the same as for `f:ajax`.